# When I convert list to dataframe in R, Chinese punctuation in colname was changed

Tags: r

When I convert `list` to `data.frame` or directly create a `data.frame` containing some Chinese punctuation, some of column name were replaced like this:

```
>list(`临床病理分型（I/II型）`=1:4)

$`临床病理分型（I/II型）`
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

```
>list(`临床病理分型（I/II型）`=1:4)%>%data.frame()

  临床病理分型.I.II型.
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
4                    4
```

```
>data.frame(`临床病理分型（I/II型）`=1:4)

  临床病理分型.I.II型.
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
4                    4
```

Comment: see `?make.names()` Your name has spaces that get replaced by `.` This is the default behavior for these cases, another example: `list("a b c"=1:4) %>% as.data.frame()` `/` is also not a good idea on a `data.frame` name

Comment: @MatiasAndina But the characters replaced by `.` are some Chinese punctuations not spaces.

Comment: Check the character encoding of your R environment or IDE like RStudio. Possibly, current setting does not support Chinese characters.

Comment: Please try `list(`临床病理分型（I/II型）`=1:4)%>%data.frame(check.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R variable names are not supposed to contain blank spaces. (See the help page `?make.names`) By default, when you make a data.frame, the names are checked and any illegal characters (such as blanks spaces) are converted to periods. However,  you can override that behavior by giving the `data.frame` function the argument `check.names = FALSE`. In your case, that would mean using.

```
list(`临床病理分型（I/II型`）= 1:4) %>% data.frame(check.names=FALSE)
```